# How to reduce time for finding ip address of all active pc in lan using java language

Tags: java

i am trying to get all ip address of active pcs in a network using java.

```
try {                                
        InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println(localhost.toString());
        byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 254; i++)
        {
            ip[3] = (byte)i;
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
            if (address.isReachable(50))
            {
                System.out.println(address + " - Pinging... Pinging");
            }
            else if (!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName()))
            {
                System.out.println(address + " - DNS lookup known..");
            }                           
         }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

This code is taking to much of time, so how to reduce this time

Comment: multi-thread it

Comment: How much time ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `public boolean isReachable(int timeout) throws IOException`. Since you have 254 adress to check, in the worst case, this will take 12.7s (254 * 50ms).

You could reduce the `timeout` value or use more than one thread to do this.

Comment: Yes, i have also checked by reducing timeout value. But its getting same time.

Answer (score 0):

Is it required to use JAVA ? You can create batchscript, which will be simpler. Netstat -a will give you list of all connected machines. You can use `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec('<your command>')` in Java. Parse the output with ButteredReader class. Also make sure Netstat is installed on your machine.

Comment: Thank u for your response. But i am want do it in java, its necessary

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible modification of your code.

8 Pings are launched at the same time. It's possible to do so because you don't need the result of `ping(n-1)` before launching `ping(n)`.

I think there's still a problem with your ping method, since it takes much more time than 50ms. I don't know enough about the corresponding methods.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;


public class ParallelPing
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        IntStream integers = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 254);
        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(8); // How many pings should be launched at the same time?
        forkJoinPool.submit(() -> integers
                .parallel()
                .forEach(i -> ping(i))).get();
    }

    private static void ping(int i) {
        System.out.println("Trying to ping " + i);
        try {
            InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            //System.out.println(localhost.toString());
            byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();
            ip[3] = (byte) i;
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
            if (address.isReachable(50)) {
                System.out.println(address + " - Pinging... Pinging");
            } else if (!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName())) {
                System.out.println(address + " - DNS lookup known..");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```